# sign_in user test rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I'm just starting to learn testing with rspec in Rails.
I have a User model and I'm trying to write a test to sign the user in.  The following works:

```
describe "user login" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "logs user in" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Log In"
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Submit"

    expect(page).to have_content("You are now logged in.")
  end
end
```

In my `application_controller.rb` I have the following method:

```
def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
  current_user = user
end

helper_method: sign_in
```

And I'm wondering why my `sign_in` method doesn't work in the following test:

```
describe "user login2" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "logs user in" do
    sign_in(user)

    expect(page).to have_content("You are now logged in.")
  end
end
```

I get the following error: `Failure/Error: sign_in(user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'sign_in'`

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind integration tests is that you interact with the interface in the same way as a regular user would. This is what you are doing in the first test using Capybara.

In the second test you would probably have to include the controller code before you can call the helper method. But the test would still not work, as you try to test if something is presented on the page, although you haven't called visit yet.

If you want to write integration tests, you should go with the first test.

If you want to write more lower level tests you can sign in the user directly from the controller, but then you have to validate it in a different way. Either through some attributes from controller/model or directly from the database.